# Load Image from URL with a Referrer Header

Tags: xamarin.forms, imagesource

I need to download static images from my CDN and display them in my Xamarin.Forms view. I'm new to Xamarin specifically and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to load an image from a byte array pulled from a HTTP request.

I have the following XAML in my View:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ImageCell ImageSource="{Binding .}">
                    
                </ImageCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

In my code behind I'm fetching the image and trying to bind to a Collection of `ImageSource` instances.

```
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ImageSource> Images { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ImageSource>();

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referer", "https://foo.bar/");
            var response = await client.GetAsync("https://foo.bar/library/5.jpg");

            byte[] image = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            var imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(image));
            this.Images.Add(imageSource);
        }
    }
```

When I do this the Image within the StackLayout is empty. I know I can instead just bind to a URL and the ImageSource can download it for me but I'm required to pass a `Referrer` Header. I can't see anyway for me to force the XAML `Image` view to allow custom headers, nor can I see a way to do it if I instantiate an instance of `ImageSource` in my code behind.

When I read the documentation on `ImageSource` it sounds like it only supports URI, File, Stream and App Resources to load images from. Since I had an array of bytes I wrapped it in a `MemoryStream` and called `ImageSource.FromStream`. Nothing loads when the app runs though - the `ImageCell` is empty.

I know the image was downloaded. I converted the `byte[]` to a Base64 string then dropped it into [Base64 to Image Decoder](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter). The image loads no problem so I know it's being downloaded properly. What I don't understand is why I can't get the image to render on a `ImageSource`.

I've also tried to just use a normal `Image` control and have the same problem.

```
    <ScrollView>
        <ContentView>
            <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding}"></Image>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentView>
    </ScrollView>
```

Am I doing something completely wrong here or is dynamic downloading of images from the internet with special Headers something I can't do in Xamarin.Forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add  `this.BindingContext = this;` in page constructor.

```
   public MainPage()
   {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = this;
   }
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed the context binding... Thanks this worked.